# Arithmetic operations in notepad using a python script

Tags: python, notepad++

There is a database of this type.

Database.ini:

```
[1 StatsObject]
InfoStat=1

[2 StatsObject]
InfoStat=2

etc.
```

The InfoStat value need multiplied by a specific modifier.

I used python script for notepad++

```
import re

FixedStat = 0
StatMod = 20
Result = 0
FixedStatStr = ""

content = editor.getText()
for row, line in enumerate(content.split('\n')):
    for m in re.finditer(r'InfoStat=[0-9]+', line):
        if(int(m.group(0).split('=').pop()) > 0):
            FixedStat = int(m.group(0).split('=').pop())
            Result = FixedStat * StatMod
            FixedStatStr = 'InfoStat=' + str(Result)
            content = re.sub(m.group(0), FixedStatStr, content)
            editor.setText(content)
```

Expected Result:

```
[1 StatsObject]
InfoStat=20

[2 StatsObject]
InfoStat=40
```

Actual Result:

```
[1 StatsObject]
InfoStat=400

[2 StatsObject]
InfoStat=40
```

I suppose that after the conversion 1 into 20,
during conversion 2 into 40,
20 also changing,
because:

```
m.group(0) == 'InfoStat = 2'
```

and i use

```
re.sub
```

for all text

Tell me, please, how to change the value of InfoStat in a specific line, without affecting others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without commenting on your effort to drive this through a specific program, the reading of the data could be considerably cleaned up by using the standard library configparser module. Here's a simplified version:

```
import configparser

StatMod = 20

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('Database.ini')

for section in config.sections():
    for k, v in config[section].items():
        if 'infostat' in k:  # configparses squashes case
            print(f"[{section}]")
            print(f"InfoStat={int(v) * StatMod}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using `split`ting by '\n\n` and replacing on each section like,

```
import re

FixedStat = 0
StatMod = 20
Result = 0
FixedStatStr = ""


_content_for_demo = """[1 StatsObject]
InfoStat=1

[2 StatsObject]
InfoStat=2
"""

content = editor.getText()
pattern = r'InfoStat=(\d+)'
for section in content.split('\n\n'):
    match = re.search(pattern, section)
    if match:
        value = int(match.group(1)) * StatMod
        val = 'InfoStat={}'.format(value)
        x = re.sub(match.group(), val, section)
        # print(x) debug
        editor.setText(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex substitution rather than the `ConfigParser` module as suggested in another answer, it's probably best to do the whole thing in one go by passing a callback to `re.sub` instead of a fixed replacement string:

```
import re

STAT_MOD = 20
STAT_EXP = re.compile("(?P<prefix>InfoStat=)(?P<stat>[0-9]+)")

def fixStat(m):
    fixed = int(m.group("stat")) * STAT_MOD
    return "{}{}".format(m.group("prefix"), fixed)

def fixContent(c):
    return STAT_EXP.sub(fixStat, c)

content = editor.getText()
editor.setText(fixContent(content))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded.

I solved my problem in the following way:

```
import configparser

StatMod = 20

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('Database.ini')

for section in config.sections():
    for k, v in config[section].items():
        if 'infostat' in k:
            OldValue = int(config.get(section, "infostat"))
            if (OldValue == 0): continue
            # print("OldValue =", OldValue)
            NewValue = int(OldValue * StatMod)
            # print("NewValue =", NewValue)
            config.set(section, "infostat", str(NewValue))
            # print(config.get(section, "infostat"))

with open('Database.ini', "w") as config_file:
    config.write(config_file)
```